# How can I read and write into another file using javascript on html website?

Tags: javascript, html, web, fs

I was trying to make a simple website where you can like click on a button and it gets counted, and it should also tell you how often it has been clicked on. I tried using fs for it since I've done something similar with a Discord bot and it worked well. But on the web, it just doesn't.
It looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
      var fs = require('fs');
      var counting = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./Storage/count.json', 'utf8'));
      var button = document.getElementById("button");

      button.onclick = function() {

          counting[count]++;

          fs.writeFile('./Storage/count.json', JSON.stringify(counting), (err) => {
              if (err) console.error(err);
          });
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <button id="button">Increment</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*(I'm sorry if there are some obvious mistakes, but I'm relatively new to this kind of stuff)*

And there is a JSON too of course

```
{"count":0}
```

Comment: where do you expect the file get written with the given path on the disk of the visitor or on the webserver?

Comment: mistake 1: `var fs = require('fs');` ... a browser isn't nodejs. mistake 2: a web page does not have access to the the clients filesystem - can you imagine what you could do if it did!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use `fs` in the browser as it is a node module.
Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

One potential route is for you to take your existing node / `fs` code and move it server side. Then you would just need to develop endpoints for your website to reach.

Otherwise you could try something like `localStorage` to store the count to the client's browser.

```
 localStorage.setItem('count', 0);
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage